# Pyueye image saving with wrong resolution

Tags: python-3.x

personally pretty new to programming and I am trying to save a high mp Image from an IDS camera using the pyueye module with python.
my Code works to save the Image, but the Problem is it saves the Image as a 1280x720 Image inside a 4192x3104

I have no idea why its saving the small Image inside the larger file and am asking if anyone knows what i am doing wrong and how can I fix it so the Image is the whole 4192x3104

```
from pyueye import ueye
import ctypes

hcam = ueye.HIDS(0)
pccmem = ueye.c_mem_p()
memID = ueye.c_int()
hWnd = ctypes.c_voidp()
ueye.is_InitCamera(hcam, hWnd)
ueye.is_SetDisplayMode(hcam, 0)
sensorinfo = ueye.SENSORINFO()
ueye.is_GetSensorInfo(hcam, sensorinfo)
ueye.is_AllocImageMem(hcam, sensorinfo.nMaxWidth, sensorinfo.nMaxHeight,24, pccmem, memID)
ueye.is_SetImageMem(hcam, pccmem, memID)
ueye.is_SetDisplayPos(hcam, 100, 100)

nret = ueye.is_FreezeVideo(hcam, ueye.IS_WAIT)
print(nret)
FileParams = ueye.IMAGE_FILE_PARAMS()
FileParams.pwchFileName = "python-test-image.bmp"
FileParams.nFileType = ueye.IS_IMG_BMP
FileParams.ppcImageMem = None
FileParams.pnImageID = None


nret = ueye.is_ImageFile(hcam, ueye.IS_IMAGE_FILE_CMD_SAVE, FileParams, ueye.sizeof(FileParams))
print(nret)
ueye.is_FreeImageMem(hcam, pccmem, memID)
ueye.is_ExitCamera(hcam)
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of the image depends on the sensor size of the camera.By printing `sensorinfo.nMaxWidth` and `sensorinfo.nMaxHeight` you will get the maximum size of the image which the camera captures. I think that it depends on the model of the camera. For me it is 2056x1542.
Could you please elaborate on the last sentence of the question.

Comment: I figured it out. you have to directly give the program the FormatID of your specific camera.

for me i had to add the following lines

 """nret = ueye.is_SetExternalTrigger(hcam, ueye.IS_SET_TRIGGER_SOFTWARE)
 FormatID = ueye.uint(33)"""

the camera was set into the wrong resolution mode

Comment: @Darron How did you solve this issue? I can not make working, can you post the code updated?

Comment: Any updates on this? I have the same problem and can't seem to figure it out. FormatID=ueye.uint(33) and then? How did you set it to the camera?